# Existence of the Limit of a Sequence of Characteristic Functions is not sufficient for Convergence in Distribution of a Sequence of R.V

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2,$ ... denote some sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on the interval $(-n,n)$ and let $\varphi_1, \varphi_2$, ... be their characteristic functions. Show that the existence of the limit $\varphi(t):= \lim_{n\to\infty} \varphi(t)$ is not sufficient in order for the sequence $(X_n)_{n\ge1}$ to converge in distribution.

This is what I have so far:

Let ${X_n}$ be uniformly distributed on the interval $(-n,n)$ then the characteristic function will be $$ \varphi_{X_n}(t) = \frac{\sin(tn)}{tn}$$ and so:

$$\varphi_{X_n}(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin(tn)}{tn} &t \ne0\\ 1&t = 0\end{cases}.$$

and then:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \varphi(t)=\begin{cases}0 &t \ne0\\ 1&t = 0\end{cases}.$$

Now, I can see that when $t = 0$ for  $t \in \mathbb{R}  $, the limiting characteristic function $\varphi(t)$ is discontinuous. So the limit exists except for when $t=0$.

Now,  $X_n$ converges in distribution to a random variable $X$ if  $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{X_n}(x) \rightarrow F(x)$ so for every $x \in \mathbb{R}  $ the cumulative distribution function $F_X$ is continuous.

I'm not very sure if I'm on the right track, and I'm also not very sure how to prove that the sequence of random variables $X_n$ fails to converge in distribution to X, also, I think that the continuity Theorem could help me but I still don't see how to make the link. I would appreciate any hint! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made couple of mistakes but they must just be typos.

$\phi_n(t)=\frac {\sin (nt)} {nt}$ if $t \neq 0$ and $1$ if $t=0$. [All characteristic functions have the value $1$ at $0$].

The limit of this is $0$ for $ t \neq 0$ and $1$ for $t=1$.

If random variables converge in distribution then (by the continuity theorem) their characteristic functions necessarily converge to the characteristic function of the limit which is necessarily a continuous function. Since the limit is not continuous in this case it follows that your sequence $(X_n)$ does not converge in distribution.